# Generator expression that resembles the behavior of append

Tags: python, generator

This is more a programming exercise than a real-world problem: I am looking for a generator expression that resembles the behavior of `append`.

Consider:

```
def combine(sequence, obj):
    for item in sequence:
        yield item
    yield obj

s = ''.join(combine(sequence, obj))
```

This generator basically resembles `append`. In the workflow of my program the above is as fast as

```
sequence.append(obj)
s = ''.join(sequence)
```

I am now wondering if there is a neat generator expression `genexpr` with

```
s = ''.join(genexpr)
```

that resembles the `append` behavior above without performance caveats.

```
s = ''.join(_ for a in [sequence, [obj]] for _ in a)
```

performs bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from `itertools` module:

```
''.join(chain(sequence, [obj]))
```

If you don't want to create a new `list` for `obj`, then you may try this:

```
''.join(chain(sequence, repeat(obj,1)))
```

I would use `[obj]` as it's more readable and I doubt that `repeat` iterator has a less overhead than `list` creation.

Comment: Thanks. In the context of my code, both variants are on a par with with `sequence.append(obj); s = ''.join(sequence)`.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke `append` may result in list extension (it's extended behind the scenes sometimes when the free space left to append new elements is out). While `chain` only creates iterator which goes through existing elements, so there can't be any memory reallocations.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke This is what I mean: "The time needed to append an item to the list is “amortized constant”; whenever the list needs to allocate more memory, it allocates room for a few items more than it actually needs, to avoid having to reallocate on each call (this assumes that the memory allocator is fast; for huge lists, the allocation overhead may push the behaviour towards O(n*n))." (from [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm))

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Please, look at the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999237/how-to-build-vectorized-building-blocks-using-itertools-module/13002722#13002722). It explains some deep details, that you may be interested in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your particular example, but I found that just using a+[b] was about as fast as anything else even with large lists.  Here is my test code:

```
import timeit
from itertools import chain, repeat

a=map(str,range(100000))
b='b'

def combine(sequence,obj):
  for item in sequence:
    yield item
  yield obj

def test1():
  return ','.join(a+[b])

def test2():
  return ','.join(combine(a,b))

def test3():
  return ','.join(chain(a,repeat(b,1)))

def test4():
  return ','.join(chain(a,[b]))

def test5():
  return ','.join(y for x in [a,[b]] for y in x)

count=100
print 'test1: %g'%timeit.timeit(test1,number=count)
print 'test2: %g'%timeit.timeit(test2,number=count)
print 'test3: %g'%timeit.timeit(test3,number=count)
print 'test4: %g'%timeit.timeit(test4,number=count)
print 'test5: %g'%timeit.timeit(test5,number=count)
```

And here are the results on my system:

```
test1: 0.475413
test2: 0.977652
test3: 0.550071
test4: 0.548962
test5: 0.968162
```

Comment: It's interesting that test 2 and 5 show equal performance here. And yes, in my code using `a+[b]` seems to be just fine. Thanks for pointing this out! Now, I am not sure, which one of you has earned the green check mark. Both of you provided valuable insights. Should we just leave it as it is? :)

Comment: I think ovgolovin answered your actual question.  This was more FYI.