# How to build “vectorized” building blocks using itertools module?

Tags: python, vectorization, python-itertools

The [recipe section](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) of `itertools` docs begins with this text:

> The extended tools offer the same high performance as the underlying
>   toolset. The superior memory performance is kept by processing
>   elements one at a time rather than bringing the whole iterable into
>   memory all at once. Code volume is kept small by linking the tools
>   together in a functional style which helps eliminate temporary
>   variables. **High speed is retained by preferring “vectorized” building
>   blocks over the use of for-loops and generators which incur
>   interpreter overhead.**

The question is, how should generators be constructed to avoid the overhead? Could you provide some examples of poor-constructed blocks which have this overhead?

I decided to ask when I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998849/generator-expression-that-resembles-the-behavior-of-append/12998890#12998849) where I couldn't say exactly if `chain(sequence, [obj])` has overhead over `chain(sequence, repeat(obj,1))`, and should I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The doc text is not about how to construct generators to avoid the overhead. It explains that correctly written `itertools`-using code, such as code provided in the examples, eschews for-loops and generators altogether, leaving it to itertools or built-in collectors (such as `list`) to consume the iterators.

Take, for example, the `tabulate` example:

```
def tabulate(function, start=0):
    "Return function(0), function(1), ..."
    return imap(function, count(start))
```

The non-vectorized way to write this would have been:

```
def tabulate(function, start=0):
    i = start
    while True:
        yield function(i)
        i += 1
```

This version "incurs interpreter overhead" because the looping and the function call is done in Python.

Regarding chaining a single element, it is safe to assume that `chain(sequence, [obj])` will be (trivially) faster because fixed-length list construction is well-optimized in Python using specialized syntax and op-codes. In the same vein, `chain(sequence, (obj,))` would be even faster, since tuples share the optimizations for lists, and are smaller to boot. As always with benchmarking, it is much better to measure with `python -m timeit` than to guess.

The documentation quote does **not** concern itself with differences in iterator creation, such as those exhibited by choosing one of `repeat(foo, 1)` and `[foo]`. Since the iterator only ever produces a single element, it makes no difference how it is consumed. The docs speak of processor and memory efficiency when dealing with iterators that can produce millions of elements. Compared to that, choosing the iterator that *creates* faster is trivial because creation strategy can be changed at any time. On the other hand, once the code is designed to use explicit loops that don't vectorize, it can be very hard to change later without a full rewrite.

Comment: May be I should formulate it as another question. But I will first begin with asking in the comments. A [recipes section](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) provides a code of `consume` generator. And it has a comment "# Use functions that consume iterators at **C speed.**". After reading that comment I started contemplating and got to the question: "But C function still have to call `next` each time on underlying iterator. Why are those calls not processed with interpreter overhead? How does Python know that underlying iterator is written in C?".

Comment: It's not the underlying iterator that is written in C, but the loop that iterates, in this case the one in `collections.deque`. If both the producer and the consumer are written in C, then the actual *interpreter* never gets involved. (Python's object model is still used, but that's different.) A loop written in a low-level compiled language will typically beat, efficiency-wise, one written in a high-level interpreted language.

Comment: Thank you! My question was about the case with "producer and the consumer", and I made an example with only consumer because of the comment "... C speed" in `consume` generator. So, you answered what I actually wanted to ask. The only thing left that I'm curious about is how Python perceives that in `imap(function, count(start))`, `imap` knows that `count` is in C, thus bypassing interpreter (because if things were implemented in a crude way, `imap` would call `next` on `count` via interpreter, which subsequently would address this to `count`'s C-code.

Comment: By the way, I'm always quite disappointed when such interesting questions and answers to them get so few upvotes.

Comment: A misunderstanding still lingers. The *interpreter* is the component of Python's implementation that goes through Python statements and expressions, such as `foo += 1` or `bar = it.next()`, and executes them. It is efficient, but it must pick apart Python bytecode and do what the bytecode tells it to do.

Comment: A working Python program modifies the state of the *virtual machine*, the environment that hosts modules, classes, objects, namespaces, etc. Since this environment is implemented in C, it can also be modified from C, by using the [Python/C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html). You could write a perfectly valid Python module entirely in C, and it would be callable from Python. `itertools` is a perfect examples, but there are others, such as `array` or `numpy`. These modules don't incur interpreter overhead because **they don't use the interpreter** —it's as simple as that.

Comment: The same goes for the `imap`/`count` combination. Python doesn't need to do anything special to avoid interpretation; if both are written in C, interpretation will simply never happen, although they will still manipulate shared data through Python's object model (which you confusingly also call "the interpreter" when saying "`next` will be called via interpreter").

Comment: Thank you for exhaustive explanation. Now the things are much more clear for me! Hope the other people, who will read this answer, will also get something new from you answer and comments!